# glCullFace is not correctly working, do you have answers for that?

Tags: c++, opengl

I am rendering a terrain and because the underside will never be seen I though face culling would bring a nice performance boost. I looked up a tutorial and came to these settings:

```
glCullFace(GL_FRONT);
glFrontFace(GL_CCW);
```

The problem is, that this is only working partially. The terrain is made out of quadrilaterals which each consist out of two right triangles and I only see one of the two triangles, if I use clockwise winding, I see the other triangle. I am using indices to safe memory and I have drawn out on paper how the windings of the indices should be but somehow it isn't working.

I generate my indices like this:

```
mapIndices[arrayIdx + 0] = i;
mapIndices[arrayIdx + 1] = i + 1;
mapIndices[arrayIdx + 2] = i + CHUNK_SIDE_LENGHT + 1;

mapIndices[arrayIdx + 5] = mapIndices[arrayIdx + 1];
mapIndices[arrayIdx + 4] = mapIndices[arrayIdx + 2];
mapIndices[arrayIdx + 3] = mapIndices[arrayIdx + 2] + 1;
```

Don't get confused over the `CHUNK_SIDE_LENGHT + 1`, I want `CHUNK_SIDE_LENGHT` triangles, so I need `CHUNK_SIDE_LENGHT + 1` vertices for one row. 
As I said, I have drawn this order on paper and the winding is correct but OpenGL doesn't like it. Could this have something to do with the index rendering?

Comment: Is this the original code? Are the indices (5 - 4 - 3) also in the original code in reverse order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot see any issue in your code.

The winding order of the 1st triangle is the same

```
0 : i
1 : i + 1
2 : i + CHUNK_SIDE_LENGHT + 1

2
 +
 | \
 |   \
 |     \         
 +-------+
0         1
```

as the winding order of the 2nd triangle:

```
3 : i + CHUNK_SIDE_LENGHT + 2
4 : i + CHUNK_SIDE_LENGHT + 1
5 : i + 1

4         3
 +-------+
   \     | 
     \   |
       \ |
         +
          5
```

Comment: @falkus7 Then the bug is somewhere else. The order  of the indices is correct.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I'm also working on this project, do you have any idea from where this error can come?

Comment: @user11914177 If the order of the indices is like that, then the issue is not caused by the indices. The graphics driver is unlikely to has a [face culling](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Face_Culling) bug. The [Primitive](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive) type is `GL_TRIANGLES`, isn't it?

Comment: @Rabbid76 The render call looks like this: `glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indicesSize, MAP_INDICES_ARRAY_GL_TYPE, 0);`

Comment: @user11914177 Is the code in the question the original code? Is `arrayIdx` incremented by 6 in a loop? There so many possible bugs. I just can guess. That makes no sense at all.

Comment: @Rabbid76 The question contains the original code, the array index is incremented by 6 and everything is working, when the face culling is off.

Comment: @user11914177 Does it work is you swap index 3 and 5? That would be strange, but does it work?

Comment: @Rabbid76 I'm absolutely confused now, for some strange reason everything works now, it works also works when the indices 3 and 5 are swapped. I don't know what has changed, I didn't do anything on the rendering only on the loading of new chunks.